# Safari ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Tmpo (= plain js class)

Tags: angular

I wrote a small angular application that makes use of a simple js class in my assets/js folder.
Everything works perfectly in my local environment (ng-serve).
When I build and deploy my app (ng build --prod) I get a **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Tmpo**. But, only in Safari...

code available here: https://github.com/flukso/flukso.github.io
site available here: https://flukso.github.io

My js class (tmpo.js)

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  timeout: 10 * 60 * 1000, // msecs
  cache: false
})

class Tmpo {
  constructor(uid, token, debug = false) {
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

in `angular.json`:

```
...
"scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/tmpo.js"
            ]
...
```

in my component:

```
import ...

declare var Tmpo: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    export() {

        const tmpo = new Tmpo(null, this.token.value, false);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u starting the production from an subfolder?

Comment: No, am hosting it in GitHub pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, got a similiar problem some days ago:

`ng build --prod --aot --service-worker --base-href ./`